# Method overload emitted via dynamic IL is not being called

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, reflection.emit, .net-7.0

So I am attempting to create a class that will wrap up all the bits necessary to implement a single-instance application (SIA).  It should be a drop-in replacement for `Application.Run<T>()`.

Since the SIA needs to override the `WndProc` method so that the running instance can bring itsself to the foreground, and that override needs to call the base class method, I landed on creating a wrapper class at runtime that inherits from whatever the `Form` class is which implements an override for `WndProc`.

The SIA portion is working, as is the wrapper class.  But the `WndProc` override does not appear to be getting called.

Any direction regarding getting the dynamic `WndProc` override to be called would be appreciated.

Code so far:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ScreenSaverControl {
    public static class SingleInstanceApplication<T> where T : Form {
        private const string APP_NAME = "SCREENSAVER_CONTROL";
        private const string COMPANY_NAME = "DWAK";

        private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
        public static readonly int WM_SHOW_RUNNING_INSTANCE = Win32Helper.RegisterWindowMessage($"WM_SHOW_RUNNING_INSTANCE_{APP_NAME}");

        private static Mutex _singleInstanceMutex = new Mutex(true, $"{APP_NAME}::{COMPANY_NAME}");

        private static Form? _instanceForm = null;
        private static Action _showRunningInstanceAction = ActivateRunningInstance;



        public static void Run() {
            MessageBox.Show(WM_SHOW_RUNNING_INSTANCE.ToString());
            if (_singleInstanceMutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true)) {
                CreateSingleInstanceFormRunner();
                Application.Run(_instanceForm);
                _singleInstanceMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            } else {
                ActivateRunningInstance();
            }
        }


        private static void ActivateRunningInstance() {
            Win32Helper.PostMessage(
                (IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST,
                WM_SHOW_RUNNING_INSTANCE,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);
        }


        private static void MessageHandler(ref Message m) {
            Debug.WriteLine($"*SIA: {m.Msg}");    // This never fires.
            if (null == _instanceForm) { return; }
            if (SingleInstanceApplication<T>.WM_SHOW_RUNNING_INSTANCE == m.Msg) {
                if (_instanceForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
                    _instanceForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                if (!_instanceForm.Visible) { _instanceForm.Show(); }

                bool topMost = _instanceForm.TopMost;
                _instanceForm.TopMost = true;
                _instanceForm.TopMost = topMost;
            }

            //base.WndProc(ref m);
        }



        delegate void RefAction(ref Message message);

        private static void CreateSingleInstanceFormRunner() {
            //if (null == _instanceForm) { return; }
            string methodName = "WndProc";
            Type type = typeof(T);
            MethodInfo? methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (null == methodInfo) {
                methodInfo = typeof(Form).GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            }
            Type[] methodParams = methodInfo!.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();

            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName("SingleInstanceAssembly");
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("SingleInstanceModule");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("SingleInstanceFormRunner", TypeAttributes.Public, type);

            // Define the new method with ref parameter
            MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodName, MethodAttributes.Private, methodInfo.ReturnType, new Type[] { typeof(Message).MakeByRefType() });
            RefAction newWndProc = MessageHandler;
            ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, newWndProc.Method);

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            Type dynamicType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            _instanceForm = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicType);
        }
    }




    internal static class Win32Helper {
        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace ScreenSaverControl {
    internal static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            SingleInstanceApplication<MainDialog>.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Test procedure + results:

1. Run the first instance via VS debug run.
2. Minimize the running instance.
3. Run the second instance via the .exe in the output folder.

- Observe the output window and notice that no "*SIA" messages are present.
- Observe that the `MessageHandler` breakpoint never fires.
- Observe that the debug (first) instance does not bring itself to the foreground.

For debugging purposes I implemented a `WndProc` override on `MainDialog` which outputs the `m.Msg` value to the output window.  I DO see those messages.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    Debug.WriteLine(m.Msg);
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I have confirmed that the running form is an instance of `SingleInstanceFormRunner`.

This code is WinForms on .NET 7.0.

Let me know if there's additional information that's needed to assist.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a hunch, looking at the code you have posted: the Method generated by MethodBuilder should specify `MethodAttributes.Family | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig` -- Not sure what `OpCodes.Ldarg_2` is in `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, newWndProc.Method);`. IMO, you should only have `OpCodes.Ldarg_1` when calling `MessageHandler()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `MethodAttributes` are incorrect, they do not represent an override of protected method, change to:

   ```cs
   MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodName,
        MethodAttributes.Family | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, 
        methodInfo.ReturnType, 
        new Type[] { typeof(Message).MakeByRefType() });
   ```
2. Your first call via IL is faulty, you are trying to call a static method with one argument, so change to:

   ```cs
   ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
   //il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
   il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
   //il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);
   il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, newWndProc.Method);
   ```
3. Still it will fail due to access level of method, make it public:

   ```
   public static void MessageHandler(ref Message m)
   {
        // ...
   }
   ```
4. I would say that there is no actual need to use `Reflection.Emit` here - switch to using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) to generate wrapper class (will need require change of API) which will do what you want.

Comment: You and Jimi are fantastic.  Thank you very much for correcting me there.  I think where I got confused was that I didn't realize I was calling the static method on SingleInstanceApplication, but rather thought that the IL for that would somehow be copied into the emitted method.. I see how that is not the case now.  Again, thank you.